# How do I print out model data without printing the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I know that this is basic, but I cannot figure it out for whatever reason.

I'm trying to return some model data and the majority of the time I return it with `pluck`, but pluck is returning an array.  How do I return the value without the array?

`<dd><%= Goal.where(id:post.attachid).pluck(:title) %></dd>`

This is the code that  I have and it is returning, for example, `["Computer"]`

How do I just make it return `Computer`

Comment: Your example code looks like it might produce [N+1 queue issues](https://medium.com/@tadhao/n-1-query-issue-in-rails-4cebef9e9785). You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting to check what's the SQL generated by activerecord (you could verify that in your console):

```
Goal.where(id: post.attachid).pluck(:title)
```

Will produce something like:

```
SELECT "goals"."title" FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."attachid" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

I guess a cheaper alternative for what you want to achieve would be:

```
Goal.select(:title).find(post.attachid).title
```

That would produce:

```
SELECT "goals"."title" FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

That are many ways you could achieve the same thing, I would advise you to experiment, observe the SQL output and find the one that suit you best.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you can do

`= Goal.where(id:post.attachid).pluck(:title).to_s`

or

`= Goal.where(id:post.attachid).pluck(:title).join(", ")`

This would produce a result like

`#> Computer, Laptop, Mouse...`

Answer (score 2):

In cases in which you expect the database to only return one record you might want to use [`find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) instead of `where`.

```
dd><%= Goal.find_by(id: post.attachid).title %></dd>
```

`find_by` always returns only a single record while `where` always returns an array-like ActiveRecord::Relation.